# EXTJS 4.2 disable close button on Ext.Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Is there a way to disable the close button in the header of a window?. I know that if you define the window with:

```
closable : false
```

the button "X" is hidden.

But I need it visible and during some operations inside the window disable the "X" button to prevent the user to close the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests and attempts, I finally achieved the following, and it works for me:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('my view')[0].getHeader().getTools()[0].setDisabled(true/false);
```